# Bootstrap LESS: duplicate @imports

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

We are using bootstrap v3.3.4.

Our structure keeps all of bootstrap's LESS source files in a separate folder for easy upgrading.

In our main `styles.less` file that compiles to `styles.css` we just `@import` all of the dependencies, including `bootstrap.less`.

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less"; // bootstrap source
@import "variables.less"; // our custom variables
@import "mixins.less"; // our custom mixins
@import "main.less"; // all of our custom css/less styles
```

Our custom `variables.less` file imports bootstrap's `variables.less` file, and our custom `mixins.less` file imports bootstrap's `mixins.less` file.

This means that in our main `styles.less`, bootstrap's `variables.less` and `mixins.less` are imported twice. (once in `bootstrap/bootstrap.less` and again in our custom `mixins.less`/`variables.less`)

The reason we are doing it this way is because we have other separate `css` files that we only include on some pages along with styles.css, and those files are compiled from their own `less` files that depend on both bootstrap's custom variables/mixins and our custom variables/mixins, which means they need to be imported in these less files.

Therefore, it's much easier to just do this:

```
@import "variables.less"; // our custom variables that also @import bootstrap's variables
@import "mixins.less"; // our custom variables that also @import bootstrap's variables
```

and not have to worry about importing all of the dependencies (bootstrap's and ours) separately since our version imports the bootstrap version.

If we tried to eliminate the duplicate imports, it would look like:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables.less";
@import "bootstrap/mixins.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

We would not only have to import twice as many files, but we would also have to worry about the order because the bootstrap files must come first.

My question is A) Will doing it our way cause problems because of duplicate imports, B) Even if it won't necessarily cause problems, does this violate any best practices, and C) Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: "This means that in our main `styles.less`, ... are imported twice." <- Actually they are not, notice ["the default behaviour"](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-once) of import statements.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yes one of the below answers cleared that up for me. So now I'm just wondering if my approach violates any best practices, and if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Well, personally I don't not think B violates any "best practices" (what you can see in most of frameworks is just a historically forced "tradition" and "legacy" since the development of some of them started in Stone Ages and then more young Frameworks just blindly copy approaches from older ones).

Comment: So I'd say it like this: "if any of your '...component.less' is also supposed to be compiled into its corresponding '...component.css' on its own, there's *nothing* wrong for it to import all the required imports... And it's OK to have imports duplicated if such components are also compiled as part of a 'all-in-one' stylesheet" (But the opposite approach is also absolutely fine so an exact choice solely depends on the specific use-case). But I don't want to write an answer because such B question is quite offtopic here ("primarily opinion-based") and it's more a subject for a blog-post.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I understand there is more than one "right" way to do things, but there are also completely wrong ways to do things. My B question is on topic, because if what I'm doing violates any standard best practices, it can be considered wrong, regardless of anyone's individual opinion on what is right.

Comment: The topic/offtopic thing is not in the B question itself but in definition of "standard best practices", simply because there's no widely adopted "best practices" for Less. It's all just like they wrote below "Just yes, it violates" (should be translated as "yes, it's probably violates things that I believe to be a  "best practices"), but with no single evidence or an example (and same way I can write "No it does not", and give no example too).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I'm new to less and bootstrap, so I'm not aware if there are any standard best practices that apply to my situation or not. An answer explaining that there are no such best practices would be completely relevant and would answer my B question. The question itself is not off-topic, so an answer is justified.

Answer (score 2):

### A) Will doing it our way cause problems because of duplicate imports?

First, the answer is no. The LESS compiler is smart enough to care about duplication of modules and declarations. Its able to distinguish and work on it.

### B) Even if it won't necessarily cause problems, does this violate any best practices?

For sure, except if the imports don't deal with side effects, if they carry only code that will not affect any other style in any way and, if compiled, would generated a CSS empty of declarations. It's not good to import twice code full of side-effects, not by twice code generation, but by good practices and legibility.

### C) Is there a better way to approach this?

Yes, you should know that imports in LESS work in compile time and, when you just compile your main file, you will be able to access variables and mixins from external sources. As an example, let's take the following:

**palette.less**:

```
@defaultColor: navy;
@secondaryColor: black;
```

**body-def.less**:

```
body {
  background-color: @defaultColor;
  border-top: 5px solid @secondaryColor;
}
```

**main.less**:

```
@import "palette";
@import "body-def";

html { ...
```

Note that `body-def` doesn't import `palette`, but it can access its data as much as `main.less` is compiled.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Your A and B points cleared up a lot for me. I understand your C point, and it makes perfect sense if all of my less was being compiled into a single css file. However, in my question I stated that I have a second .css file that is completely separate and is compiled from different .less files. This is because that .css file is only needed on some pages, not all. This second .css file still needs to have access to the variables and mixins from my main styles.css file. Unless I'm mistaken, this means I do need to import the variables.less and mixins.less

Answer (score 0):

**A) Will doing it our way cause problems because of duplicate imports**

Nope

**B) Even if it won't necessarily cause problems, does this violate any best practices**

Yes. A common way to use CSS preprocessors is to have a single file control everything, this being your `styles.less` file. The mentality should be to have a single rule them all, find them all, and bring them all together (in regards to imports). So if you're importing things twice or more, then a single file isn't bringing them all together nor is them finding all.

**C) Is there a better way to approach this?**

LESS doesn't work like other object oriented languages where you have to import a specific header to use a mixin. By simply compiling `styles.less` (your main LESS file) it will automatically be able to go into Bootstrap and call the proper mixins.

Some IDEs are incapable of handling mixins from other files without an implicit @import so it won't give you hints but LESS itself can handle it no problem; that's actually how it's meant to be. You may just need to find another plugin for the IDE or have the Bootstrap documentation next to you if the intellisense hints are what you require.

One approach you can follow is to create a "common.less" file that you can use in your project. For example:

**common.less**

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less"; // bootstrap source
@import "variables.less"; // your custom variables
@import "mixins.less"; // your custom mixins
```

**styles.less**

```
@import "common.less";

// Your common CSS
```

**unique.less**

```
@import "common.less"

// Custom CSS per page
```

With this approach, you're only importing things once and you don't have to worry about managing things separately in each file. Just be sure, you don't import any LESS files that actually output CSS in your `common.less` or else you'll have duplicate rules in your CSS files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. More explanation for the B point would be nice. As far as your C point goes, it makes perfect sense if all of my less was being compiled into a single css file. However, in my question I stated that I have a second .css file that is completely separate and is compiled from different .less files. This is because that .css file is only needed on some pages, not all. This second .css file still needs to have access to the variables and mixins from my main styles.css file. Unless I'm mistaken, this means I do need to import the variables.less and mixins.less

Comment: You're importing all of bootstrap in common.less, so every separate file will have all of bootstrap's css.

Comment: @wired_in oh I'm sorry! You do make an excellent point. Seems my answer won't be of much use